# How to make requests.post not to wrap dict values in arrays in python?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I use python requests.post function to send json queries to my django app.

```
r = requests.post(EXTERNAL_SERVER_ADDRESS, data={'123':'456', '456':'789'})
```

But on the external server request.POST object looks like this:

`<QueryDict: {'123': ['456'], '456': ['789']}>`

Why does it happen? How can I just send a dict?

Comment: I think the reason why you don't have a simple dict is because you may have several times the same key in your request. Try a curl with --data k=1&k=2 and I am ready to bet Django serve you the two values.

Answer (score 1):

requests is not doing anything here. Presumably your receiving server is Django; that's just how it represents data from a request. `request.POST['123']` would still give '456'.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a dict, Django transform this JSON in this QueryDict objetc automatically when it receives the message. If you want to parse it to an dict, do:

```
myDict = dict(queryDict.iterlists())
```